# Why does malloc(0) return a non-null address in Windows?

Tags: c, memory-management, malloc

The code below returns an address when executed in Windows, though I was expecting it to return NULL.

```
int main()
{
   char *ptr = NULL;
   ptr = malloc(0);
   printf("malloc returned = %u\n", ptr);

}
```

What could have prompted such an implementation of malloc? Is there any reason behind it?

Since, this is a 0 byte memory, I didn't experiment writing any data. But, can this memory be used for anything at all?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's just the minimum size you're requesting. And since there are no zero-length blocks in the Win32 heap, you can:

```
void *p = malloc(0);
// ... do some stuff in between...
realloc(p, n);
```

Which should mostly result in reusing a block of the heap (if you're lucky and the new size is small). A minor opportunist optimization (or a slow-down, depending on the context and blood coffee-levels).

This is a simplified example. The actual situation could be a class that allocates a buffer when it's created and also allows to grow it. If the inputs are annoying to control, you could just let it do that zero-sized buffer allocation.

Comment: +1 as I've actually seen 1 person use this to his "advantage" when he did not want to special case anything in a loop that could grow the malloc'd/realloc'd memory very large.

Comment: You can pass a null pointer into `realloc`, though, so this trick is in no way essential. You could just as well `void *p = 0;`.

Comment: @Steve It's not really a trick. It's an artifact of programming and loose platform specifications. Without testing, it is not clear how HeapRealloc(heap, HEAP_REALLOC_IN_PLACE_ONLY, 0, 4) would behave, for example.

Comment: @user1240436: I meant "trick" in the sense of "little programming technique". My point was just that JimR's friend didn't need to do this in order to avoid special-casing that loop. Starting from a null pointer would have worked.

Comment: A more interesting scenario would be allocating something of non-zero size, then using `realloc` to resize it to zero, and then using another `realloc` to resize it to its original size.  Efficiency may be improved by having "shrinking" realloc calls leave memory at least "weakly" reserved, so it may be given back to the original object if it wants to grow back to its earlier size.  If a zero-size realloc(0) returned null, the system couldn't know to whom it should give back the block.  If zero-size realloc can return non-null, there's no reason a zero-sized malloc shouldn't as well.

Answer (score 8):

To answer the second part of your question no, the memory can't be used for anything, since "the accessible part of it" is 0 bytes starting from the address returned.

IIRC it is guaranteed though that if the implementation does return non-null, then it will be a *different* address from any other currently allocated memory block. So in theory you could use the address as a temporary unique ID (of pointer type), although obviously there are plenty of other ways of getting a unique ID. And even if you were going to use it for that, `malloc(1)` would work just as well as `malloc(0)` and be more portable.

Answer (score 7):

That's answered within the comp.lang.c FAQ: http://c-faq.com/ansi/malloc0.html

> The ANSI/ISO Standard says that it may do either; the behavior is implementation-defined (see question 11.33). Portable code must either take care not to call malloc(0), or be prepared for the possibility of a null return.

Comment: But, what would make an implementation choose to return some valid value? Doesn't it make sense to return NULL in all cases?

Comment: Not necessarily. I shudder to second-guess compiler writers, but an implementer could want malloc to return `null` only if memory can not truly be allocated.

Comment: @Jay: since the implementation is free to do either, it might well decide to do whichever is less code. It's reasonable to decide not to trouble yourself to write an extra line of code to test the input for 0 and return a null pointer. Then again, if the implementation already has a test that the required size isn't absurdly huge (and will return a null pointer if it is), then it might be just as easy to check for absurdly-huge-or-zero.

Answer (score 3):

the standard says it can do either

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/malloc.html

Answer (score 0):

It is NOT useless. Blocks that are returned from malloc are expected to be unique. Thus each block returned by malloc carries both the data within the block and a unique identifier for it, being its address. If the latter property is important, and the fact that it contains no data is not an issue, then it is useful.

However, as mentioned its a great way to write non-portable code. This is NOT the same thing as illegal code, however, and it is perfectly valid for an implementation to support it (as apparently windows does).