# How to copy a buffer to a character pointer in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, character

So I have a character array of fixed size:

```
char buff[100];
```

And I have a character pointer:

```
char *ptr;
```

Now, the buffer will be filled partially or fully. I want to copy the contents of the buffer to ptr. How do I do that?

Thanks

Update:

```
int rcd; // Received bytes
int temp = 0; // This is used as a size to realloc the dataReceived character pointer
int packetLength = 0; // This is the total packet length
int *client = (int*) data;
int cli = *client; // The client socket descriptor
char buff[100]; // Buffer holding received data
char *dataReceived = malloc(0);

while ((rcd = recv(cli, buff, 100, MSG_DONTWAIT)) > 0) 
{
    dataReceived = realloc(dataReceived, rcd + temp + 1); // Realloc to fit the size of received data
    strcat(dataReceived, buff); // Concat the received buffer to dataReceived
    temp = rcd;
    packetLength = packetLength + rcd;
    memset(buff, 0, 100); // Reinitialize the buffer for the next iteration
}
```

Comment: This is very incomplete! Where is the code? You need to show what `ptr` points to! And it's also important What are the contents of `buff`?

Comment: [`strcpy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy)

Comment: @BryanChen If `ptr` points to valid memory and `buff` is a `nul` terminated sequence, that's why I say there is a lot missing in this question.

Comment: so I'm using buff to read data coming in from a socket. And atm I have char *ptr = malloc(0). I want to realloc ptr when the data comes in and copy data from buff to ptr. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yeah.   Without further defining ' filled partially or fully.', no safe answer is possible.

Comment: ...so, the socket read/recv returned a byte count, then?

Comment: @MartinJames yes it did.

Comment: @iharob  Added the code

Comment: @user3266083 `malloc(0)`? What?

Comment: `dataReceived = realloc(dataReceived, rcd + temp + 1);` generally bad even if you have `64`GB of RAM. `strcat(dataReceived, buff);` very likely wrong because data sent through a socket could or not be `nul` terminated (i.e. A string).

Comment: @iharob So how do I store the entire packet data when I don't know its size? So for example, in the while loop above, when it finishes reading data of an entire packet, its going to pop out of the loop. Now if the packet size > buff its going to overwrite the buffer. So when it overwrites, I'm gonna loose data if I do not save it to some other location. So how do I do that? How do I store data to some other location so that even if buff gets overwritten I still have the old data. And then I can simply concat the new data.

Comment: You do know the size!!!!!!!! What do you think the return value of [`recv(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/recvmsg.2.html) is? And AFAIK `malloc(0)` is UNDEFINED BEHAVIOR! Not sure, but I think it is - Correction, it's [implementation defined](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10684612/1983495).

Comment: @iharob You are right. I suck! Sorry my bad. So should I just malloc the return value of recv to dataReceived and strcpy buff to it?

Comment: You mean you want to copy the buffer's contents *to the buffer ptr points to*, right? Not to ptr itself, that would make no sense.

Comment: @immibis Yes that's correct

Comment: Not `strcpy()` -- `memcpy()` because you know the length! And you can ensure that it's`nul` terminated, also you would not need `strcat()` which is the worst c library function ever.

Comment: @iharob Perfect! Thanks a lot man! Really appreciate it. :)

Comment: @iharob you sure?  I would have gone with strtok()..... :)

Comment: @MartinJames, when it's about strings in c, you should always remember that library functions will all search for the `nul` terminating byte, as long as it's possible to avoid that you improve your program's performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To copy the contents of `buffer` to wherever `ptr` points to, use:

```
memcpy(ptr, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
```

The first argument to `memcpy` is the destination, second is the source (same order as `strcpy` and `strcat`), and the third is the number of bytes to copy.

Answer (score 0):

So it will be like

```
char buff[100]; // Buffer holding received data
char *ptr;
memcpy(ptr, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
```

right ?
also if you want to free the buffer
we can use

```
free(buffer);
```

right?